# Finding a Nested <li>, and modifying it

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I'm writing a very conflated Android Unit Conversion application, using all kinds of terrible things to make it pretty.  Essentially its executing JS via vebviews, and displaying html formatted according to arbitrary size lists in fancy spinners, with abbreviations underneath... blah blah...

Anyway.  Right now I've got somthing like this:

```
for (l = 0; l < this.slotData.length; l += 1) {
    out += '<li>' + this.slotData[l].values[i] + " "+'<li class="sw-right">'+this.slotData[l].abbreviations[i]+'</li></li>';
}
```

Where slotData[l] represents say "Milimeters" and abbreviations is "Mm", which is underneath, and formatted slightly differently.  The idea is that you can enter numbers, and they will show up, underneath the Large Milimeters, next to the small Mm, so that you can see "4400mm".

I'm trying to access and modify the child li, of class "sw-right" at a different point in my code.  Wondering if anyone knows an easy way to do this?  I can access the parent without trouble, but I'm not sure what the proper way to go from there is...

My access is somthing like this:

```
this.slotEl[slot].......
```

Anythoughts?

Thanks guys...

Nathaniel.

Comment: Could you show an [SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained Correct/Compilable Example)](http://sscce.org/) [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you're working with?

Comment: I can, but it will have to wait until tomarrow.  The code is substantial at this point, so paring it down to somthing short will take me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to nest `<li>` elements.  HTML syntax does not permit nesting list items.  Since the `</li>` closing tag is optional, a browser might well just treat your nested item as a sibling of the first one anyway, and discard the second close tag as a double-close on the second item.

Addional:  Since you are trying to compose a list item of two parts, maybe what you really want is a [definition list](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/lists/dl.html).  For setting attributes on ranges nested inside of tags, consider using [span](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/span.html).

Comment: Upvoting for the fantastic Link Sparky.  I've been looking for good docs for a few days, best I've seen thus far.  Thanks.

Comment: Excellent answer sparky.  Could you talk briefly about how to access DT's??  I'm sure I'll figure it out, but I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using jquery:

```
$('li.sw-right').html('html_you_want_set');
```

Comment: Thanks Pita.  I'm about three days into JS (and HTML, and CSS and android ;-)) so i'm trying to avoid Jquery at the moment.  Let me have a week before I swallow another pill haha.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I understand.  I was at that stage once too.  Everything manipulation wise is easier with jQuery though, it's really a great tool.

Comment: Not 24 hours later and I'm eating the words.  Good call pita.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
var myNestedLI = document.getElementsByClassName( 'sw-right' )[ 0 ]
```

or

```
var topElements = document.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );

var nestedElements = []

for( var i = 0; i < topElements.length; i ++ )
{

var theseElements = topElements[ i ].getElementsByTagName( 'li' )

for( var j = 0 ; j < theseElements.length; j ++ ) nestedElements.push( theseElements[ j ] )

}

// nestedElements now contains all nested LI elements
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sparky pointed out, you can't nest `<li>` tags like that. The second li will be treated as a separate list item from the first, making them siblings. Instead what you want are two separate `<div>`s inside your `<li>`. Div is a generic block-level element. *(Block-level means there's a line break between them, and generic means that the div's meaning and style is entirely up to you.)*

I'd suggest this more descriptive markup:

```
<li class="calculated-value">
  <div class="unit">*large unit name*</div>
  <div class="value">*small value with abbreviation*</div>
</li>
```

In your CSS, the following rule will make the value div display smaller:

```
li.calculated-value div.value { font-size: 75%; }
```

(You can add additional rules to give it an indentation, better spacing, bold or color settings, etc. And you can add another line for div.unit that styles that one separately.)

Comment: Hey Richard, thanks for the answer.  I'm having some difficutly getting this to work, even with only one div element.  I'm not sure but

    out += '<li><div>' + this.slotData[l].values[i] + '</div></li>';

is the code i'm trying and its not rendering anything.  Maybe you see a problem I'm not?  Thanks.

Comment: If it's not rendering anything, maybe you have a problem with this.slotData or you're not putting it inside a `<ul>` or `<ol>`. (`<li>` elements outside a list tag are meaningless.) I'd call alert(this.slotData[l].values[i]) (or console.log() if you know how to use that) and make sure you're passing good data and that the result of `out` is being inserted properly into the page.

Comment: Thanks Rich, got it sorted.  Very much appreciate your response.